# JavaScript initialize Google Map without longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working with the Google Map API. I need to initialize the map, but I don't want to put in the longitude and latitude when this happens. However, the longitude and latitude can be displayed as an option to the user, and the Google Map can be the whole Earth as well. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  A set of latitude/longitude coordinates (a google.maps.LatLng) is required to initialize the map.  You can pick a set of coordinates and a zoom level that shows the entire world if you like.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

> center | LatLng | The initial Map center. **Required**.